# Sharepoint: Binding GridView with SharePoint List (Client Object Model)

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject

I want to show a list on an .aspx site. Therefore I have to use the SP client object model.

I found the following tutorial, but this doesn't use the client libraries:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30287.binding-gridview-with-sharepoint-list.aspx

My code so far looks the following:

```
ClientContext clientContext = GetContext(accessToken);

Web web = clientContext.Web;
clientContext.Load(web);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

// Get the email input list.
List inboxList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("InboxList");
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection items = inboxList.GetItems(new CamlQuery());

 clientContext.Load(inboxList);
 clientContext.Load(items, ic => ic.Include(i => i["DisplayName"], i => i["Client_Title"], i => i["HasUniqueRoleAssignments"]));
 clientContext.ExecuteQuery();



 foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem i in items)
 {
     clientContext.Load(i);
 }

 clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
 oGrid.DataSource = items;
 oGrid.DataBind();
```

But this shows only some "meta data" of the list item collection, see screenshot:
[image]

If I use `oGrid.DataSource = inboxList;` I get an `InvalidOperationException` because the data source isn't type of IListSource, IEnumerable nor IDataSource.

If I use `oGrid.DataSource = inboxList.DataSource;` I get an `PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException`, but I don't know how to load this attribute (via clientContext.Load it didn't work)?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it - works with following code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        ...
            ClientContext clientContext = GetContext(accessToken);

            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            clientContext.Load(web);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            // Get the email input list.
            List inboxList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("InboxList");
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection items = inboxList.GetItems(new CamlQuery());

            clientContext.Load(inboxList);
            clientContext.Load(items);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem i in items)
            {
                clientContext.Load(i);
            }
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            oGrid.DataSource = GetInboxListData(inboxList, items);
            oGrid.DataBind();

        }
        else if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Response.Write("Could not find a context token.");
            return;
        }
    }

    private DataTable GetInboxListData(List inboxList, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection items)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("From");
        dt.Columns.Add("To");
        dt.Columns.Add("Subject");
        dt.Columns.Add("Body");
        dt.Columns.Add("Attachments");
        dt.Columns.Add("Sent");

        DataRow row;

        foreach(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item in items)
        {
            row = dt.Rows.Add();
            row["From"] = item["From1"].ToString();
            row["To"] = item["To"].ToString();
            row["Subject"] = item["Subject1"].ToString();
            row["Body"] = item["Body1"].ToString();
            row["Attachments"] = item["Attachments"].ToString();
            row["Sent"] = item["Sent"].ToString();
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

This is similar to [Retrieve the values from a list to  Gridview in SharePoint Webpart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360863/retrieve-the-values-from-a-list-to-gridview-in-sharepoint-webpart) but with client object model methods & objects.